# Bootstrap Grids Doubts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm literally not able to think about anything else, this is bothering me so much.

Why the Grids in boostrap.css have different *media queries* for `.col-sm-*, .col-md-*` etc. but the `flex: ;` & `max-width: ;` inside are the same for all of them?!

Why didn't they use a "*wildcard selector*" and have them defined once?

something like this:

```
[class*="col-1-"] { flex: 0 0 8.333333%; max-width: 8.333333%; }
[class*="col-2-"] { flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%; }
```

instead of

```
.col-sm-1 { flex: 0 0 8.333333%; max-width: 8.333333%; }
.col-sm-2 { flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%; }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: i guess max-width stands here for older browsers .... where flex is not supported :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is that way because so you can use something like this in your html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">1st column</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">2nd column</div>
</div>
```

what that does basically is, if the screen size is `min-width: 576px` use `.col-sm-6` instead of the other two.

A `.col-md-*` class is only defined inside a media query, therefore active only if the screen width matches that media query.

Doing it the way you suggest is not going to work, because that class will be always active.

Hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: dude! that makes sense actually. I never thought you could do that. I always harcoded it lmao.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess same goes for row-* offset-* and the others.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Because whether it is `col-sm-1` or `col-md-1` both `flex` and `max-width` will have the same value, since it's a percentage value (meaning it will always be that percentage of the parent)

**Per example:**
for `col-sm-1` the max-width will be always `8.333333%` of the parent's width...etc